# HTML E-Mail Text to Icon conversion iOS

Tags: html, ios, email, icons

I am using a triangle in my text. In iOS this triangle is automatically converted to an icon. I cannot find the solution, how to choke it.
Here is how it looks like: [Preview on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nXk5.png)

This is what I tried out to fix it:

Code in header:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="url=no">
```

Code in element containing the triangle:

```
<p><strong class="text-green" x-ms-format-detection="none">&#9654; Tech Data Vertrieb</strong><span class="hide-for-large"><br></span> <span class="show-for-large">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>Tel.: 089 / 4700-2646 &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;">DE_GCC_SPS@techdata.com</a></p>
```

Comment: Possible solution: https://litmus.com/community/discussions/758-stop-ios-converting-html-entity-unicode-to-emoji

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was searching for it for hours. I have to confess, that i am using litmus. feeling stupid. You made my day!